MDI is not showing most recent variations of forms/windows
I'm making an MDI right now that is linked to multiple different forms ("Add Item," "About," etc). I don't think the context is too important because my issue is when I edit the different child forms, the new versions don't show up when I run the program. I included the full code from my parent form (frmParent) and my add item form (frmAdd)
namespace MDIDemo
{
    public partial class frmParent : Form
    {
        public static LibraryClass l1 = new LibraryClass();

        public frmParent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Allocate memory for our about box
            frmAboutBox frmAbt = new frmAboutBox();

            // Assign the parent:
            frmAbt.MdiParent = this;        // This is the parent/main form

            frmAbt.Show();
        }

        private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
            {
                ActiveMdiChild.Close();
            }
        }

        private void closeAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (ActiveMdiChild != null)
            {
                ActiveMdiChild.Close();
            }
        }

        private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void cascadeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
        }

        private void tileHorizontalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
        }

        private void tileVerticalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
        }

        private void arrangeIconsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.ArrangeIcons);
        }

        private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Allocate memory for our add box
            frmAdd add1 = new frmAdd();

            // Assign the parent:
            add1.MdiParent = this;    // This is the parent/main form

            add1.Show();
        }

        private void showItemsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmShow show1 = new frmShow();
            
            show1.MdiParent = this;

            show1.Show();
        }
    }
}


namespace MDIDemo
{
    public partial class frmAdd : Form
    {
        public frmAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnClr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtISBN.Clear();
            txtAuth.Clear();
            numNum.Value = 0; 
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ItemRec item1;
            
            item1.iSBN = "ISBN";
            item1.AuthorName = "Last First";
            item1.numOwned = 0;
            item1.numOnLoan = 0;

            try
            {
                item1.iSBN = txtISBN.Text;
                item1.AuthorName = txtAuth.Text;
                item1.numOwned = Convert.ToInt32(numNum.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(txtISBN.Text + " is not an integer.",
                                                "Data entry error",
                                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }



            // Add the item to our list: 

            try
            {
                frmParent.l1.Insert(item1);
            }
            catch (ListIsFullException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
                               "Data entry error",
                               MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                               MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

        private void frmAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

I have no real idea what to try, I tried simply deleting and retyping the declarations and whatnot but (unsurprisingly) that didn't seem to do anything.

Okay, I fixed it. First I tried deleting the bin folder and then rebuilding the solution, but that didn't work, so I stepped back and I think I deleted the project folder, then tried to rebuild, it didn't work, so I undid my delete and ran it and I believe it worked after that. I'm confused but at least it's running. If anyone has any idea why that happened and wants to share please feel free.

Cached WinForms controls go in the ".vs" folder - did you delete that?
